# how will I send Mail using SSMTP

Tags: java, email, ssmtp

```
 props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", portnumber);
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

I am using this code for sending email in java using my linux machine.
Please tell me which OS service  it is using internally currently for sending mail.and
I want to change this service to ssmtp . How will I send through ssmtp.

Answer (score 0):

The code you show seems to use the Java Mail API, which is included in your java project and used here as an SMTP client to send the mail. The SMTP server used here is : smtp.office365.com

However, ssmtp is not a service as you mentioned. It is another email client.

I invite you to have a deeper look into these tools to have a clearer idea before using them.

Comment: how I use ssmtp in java code. Please share your comments

Comment: If you just need to send a mail, I would recommend you use the java mail implementation. But if you really need ssmtp, you can launch the corresponding command from java using ProcessBuilder: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: Is it possible to send email through processbuilder. currently my email has template so plz tell how will i send code to this template

Comment: <p align="left" style="color:#000000;">Your appointment with <b>%%provider_name%%</b> has been scheduled:</p>
%%provider_name%%
<br/>
<mytag style="color:5c5c5d;">%%date_time%%, %%date_time_mst%%</mytag>
<br/>
<br/>
<mytag style="display:block;clear:both;"><b>Notes:</b></mytag>
<mytag style="color:5c5c5d;">%%additional_info%%</mytag>
<br/>
<hr>

Comment: template looks above code like that the variable that are coming between %% are send through method

Comment: In this case, you would better stay with the java mail API implementation.